# Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'System.Linq.dll' could not be found

Tags: powershell, windows-7, openstack

working through the automation listed here - https://github.com/cloudbase/windows-openstack-imaging-tools and have queries to github as well, but thought this would also be a helpful site to query to.

Here is a snippet of the code that the error is referencing.  I understand that I'm not including the entire script (ie, we don't have information on what $code is), but seeing if anything in the actual line of code could be improved or causing the error.  Thanks!

Code:

```
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'WIMInterop.WimFile').Type)
{
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Xml","System.Linq","System.Xml.Linq"
}
```

Error:

```
Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'System.Linq.dll' could not be found
(1) : /*
At C:\windows-openstack-imaging-tools-master\Interop.ps1:1353 char:13
+     Add-Type <<<<  -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Xml","System.Linq","
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (error CS0006: M...ld not be found:CompilerError)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Linq` namespace is not contained in a dedicated assembly.

Most of the classes (like [`Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) for example) are found in `System.Core.dll`, so reference the `System.Core` assembly instead